# How to access nativeElement by ContentChild

Tags: angular

I have a custom component like this

my component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <!-- other content -->
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ContentChild('edit', { read: TemplateRef }) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ViewChild('edit', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.template?.elementRef.nativeElement);
    // output is <!--container-->
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.input);
    //output is undefined
  }
}
```

And I'm using like this

```html
<my-component>
  <div>other content</div>
  <ng-template #edit>
    <input>
  </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

While the  element can be rendered properly, but console.log output is `<!--container-->` so I can't access the  nativeElement.

I also tried this

```
<my-component>
   <input #edit>
</my-component>
```

And then the variable `template` came to be `undefined`.

I want to access the  element and add event listener on it, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{ read: ElementRef }` for `@ContentChild`:

```
@ContentChild('element', { read: ElementRef }) element?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child component use ng-content like this

child.component.html

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

and then inside the ts file of the child component, we use the @ContentChild decorator like this:

child.component.ts

```
 @ContentChild('projectedContent') content: ElementRef;
    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.content);
     }
```

Either you console the `this.content` or `this.content.nativeElement` data will be same

the alias `projectedContent` inside the @ContentChild decorator is the reference to the element of the child that will be used inside the parent component like this

parent.component.html

```
<app-child>
<p #projectedContent> Some Data</p>
</app-child>
```

So, this is the complete code snippet.
Hope, It helps.